# Upload speed of GCE instance

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I am running gsutil upload from "us-central1-a/machineTypes/n1-standard-1" instance with attached disk to GCS bucket using -m option.

I am copying several files at once and I am getting around 15MiB TX speed according to bmon.
Is it expected speed from internal network on Google cloud?

Does upgrading instances improve the speed (note that the cpu usage of the instance is very low).

Comment: There is a command for testing performance via gsutil: 'gsutil perfdiag'.

You can choose a file size with the -s flag and run a command like:
"gsutil perfdiag -s 100MB -n 25 -k 5 -c 5 -t rthru,wthru gs://yourbucket" to get a sense of throughput.  See gsutil help perfdiag for more information.

Comment: You will get more throughput with higher CPU instance types. Try uploading with an n8.

Comment: @jterrace how the instance type can be changed from the Google Cloud Console? I see App Engine, Compute Engine and Container Engine Option under Compute Option.